# How can I use a right click context menu on a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've created a context menu, and associated to my DataGridView control. However, I noticed that when I right click on the control, the selection in the dataGridView isn't changed. So I can't correctly fetch the row in the context's event handler.

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Imagine I have an ID olumn, and when I click the delete context menu, I want to delete that particular entry from the database.

I just need the information on **how to get that id**, I can handle the deleting myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add,

```
DataGridViewRow currentRow;
void DataGridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        currentRow = self.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    else
        currentRow = null;
}
```

Then use currentRow in your context menu method.

Comment: It will if you add the CellMouseDown handler to the grid.

Answer (score 3):

```
    private void dataGridViewSource_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right || e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == -1) return;
        dataGridViewSource.CurrentCell = dataGridViewSource.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        contextMenuStripGrid.Show(Cursor.Position);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could show context menu and select current cell if a cell is clicked.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[hit.ColumnIndex, hit.RowIndex];
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(dataGridView1, e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

In Click event handler from your menu item check dataGridView1.CurrentRow to find out which row is currently selected. For example, if the grid is bound to a datasource:

```
private void test1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
}
```

When you test this code, make sure that DataGridView.ContextMenuStrip property is not set.

Comment: @shindigo - sorry, I was confused, I didn't notice that this wasn't your question in the first place :).